# How to train a ML model converting text to code

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, code-generation, huggingface-transformers

Looking for a working example Colab/Notebook showing training or fine-tuning of a text generation model capable of converting "short text" -> "programming code text".

I'm learning the topic and would like to fine-tune it with a custom metric on some public GitHub repos.

All I found so far are models that "continue a sentence" or simply generate the text out of the blue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, You can see [CodeXGLUE](https://microsoft.github.io/CodeXGLUE/) and their [repository](https://github.com/microsoft/CodeXGLUE), we have four categories:

- code-code (clone detection, defect detection, cloze test, code completion, code repair, and code-to-code translation)
- text-code (natural language code search, text-to-code generation)
- code-text (code summarization)
- text-text (documentation translation)

You want **`text-to-code generation task`**. Base benchmark on **CodeXGLUE**, one of the best models for this task is `CoTexT`. `CoTexT` support these programming languages : *"go" ,"java", "javascript", "php", "python", "ruby"*. You can find the **pre-trained** of this model on [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/) from [`here`](https://huggingface.co/razent/cotext-2-cc) and explaining about how to fine-tune this [`here`](https://github.com/justinphan3110/CoTexT/blob/main/code_generation/CodeGenerationUni.ipynb).